# Submitting a complex dynamic form to mysql db table

Tags: php

Im trying to submit a form used for daily checks of fire department apparatus. The form is a while loop and displays the name of the check as well as 3 buttons for pass, warning, and fail. There is also a comment button for each check that when clicked, a line will popup and allow the user to type in a comment.

Keep in mind!!! Every form is different. Every truck has different checks and a different quantity of checks. Some trucks can have up to 200 checks. I need this to work for every truck.

Whenever I submit the form, I get PHP errors that say:

```
Undefined array key "appnamesubmit"
 
Undefined array key "date"

Array to string conversion
```

This is my last step in getting my web-app completed. I just need to be able to submit the truck check form data to the mysql db table.

This is the truck check form for one of the trucks:

[image: Here is my form]

This is my table (truck_check_log) Im open to redesigning/renaming columns in the table.:

[image: Here is my table]

This is my form code:

```
 <div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
             
<h2 align="center"><?php echo $appname?></h2><br />
     <?php date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); $date = date("m-d-Y H:i");?>
     
   <div class="form-group">
        <form name="add_name" id="add_name" method=POST action=truck-check-submit.php>
                    
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
        
   <?php while ($checks = mysqli_fetch_array($checksqry)) {
            echo '<input type=hidden name=xid[] value='. $checks['id']. '>';
            echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td style="width: 20%">'.$checks['check_name'].' <input type=hidden name=checkname[] id=checkname value="'.$checks['check_name'].'"> <br><br> 
             <br><br> 
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btn['. $checks['id']. ']" id="btnpass[' . $checks['id'] . ']" value="Pass">
            <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-success" for="btnpass[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Pass</label>&Tab;&Tab;

            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btn['. $checks['id'] . ']" id="btnwarning[' . $checks['id'] .']" value="Warning">
           <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-warning" for="btnwarning[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Warning</label>&Tab;&Tab;

            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btn['. $checks['id'] .']" id="btnfail[' . $checks['id'] . ']" value="Fail">
           <label class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-danger" for="btnfail[' . $checks['id'] . ']">Fail</label>&Tab;&Tab;

           <button onclick="myFunction('. $checks['id'] . ')" type="button" name="comment[' . $checks['id'] . ']" id="comment[' . $checks['id'] . ']" class="btn btn-info" style="float: right"><img src="assets/comment.png" width="20px"></button> 
<br><br>
           <div style="display:none;" id="commentlinediv[' . $checks['id'] . ']">
           <input type="text" name=xcomment[] class="text-line" placeholder="Type Comment Here" id="commentline[' . $checks['id'] . ']"/>
</div>
</td>'; 

echo '<tr>';}?>

 </table>
<input placeholder="<?php echo $appname ?>" name="appnamesubmit" id="appnamesubmit" hidden="hidden"><br>
<input placeholder="<?php echo $date ?>" name="submitdate" id="datesubmitted" hidden="hidden"><br>
<input placeholder="<?php echo $firstname . " " . $lastname ?>" name="submittedby" id="submittedby" hidden="hidden"> 
</form> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
</div>
      
</div>
```

This is my php submit code:

```
include "config.php";

      $appnamesubmit = $_POST['appnamesubmit'];
    $datesubmit = $_POST['submitdate'];
    $submittedby = $_POST['submittedby'];


foreach ($_POST["xid"] as $index => $id) {
    
    $checkname = $_POST['checkname'][$index];
    $status = $_POST['btn'][$id];
    $comment = $_POST['xcomment'][$index];


    $Insert_check = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO truck_check_log (appname,check_name,status,comment,submitted_by,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ");
    $Insert_check->execute(array($appnamesubmit, $checkname, $status, $comment, $submittedby, $datesubmit));

    if($Insert_check)
    {
        echo"1 record added";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Error in insertion of the record";
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Added picture for @Ken Lee

[image: edited db table]

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The asker's recent edit has invalidated the accepted answer.

Comment: A prepared statement should be declared only once (before looping).  Only the parameters and the execution belongs in the loop.  The else branch on checking the outcome is never going to be reached. https://3v4l.org/CRTrP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A) Please change the following line in your submission form:

```
echo '<td style="width: 20%">'.$checks['check_name'].' <input type=hidden name=checkname id=checkname value='.$checks['check_name'].'>
```

to

```
 echo '<td style="width: 20%">'.$checks['check_name'].' <input type=hidden name=checkname[] id=checkname value="'.$checks['check_name'].'"> <br><br>
```

(i.s. change checkname to checkname[])

(B) For the PHP, you have a number of places that require amendments

- $_POST['date'] should be $_POST['submitdate'] - your submission form use the name `submitdate`
- $_POST['appnamesubmit'], $_POST['submitdate'] and $_POST['submittedby'] are all not inside the loop in your submission form (they are not elements of arrays), so move them out from the PHP foreach loop too
- you need to properly specify the array index inside your loop

So, change your PHP code to the following and re-try

```
<?php
include "config.php";

    $appnamesubmit = $_POST['appnamesubmit'];
    $datesubmit = $_POST['submitdate'];
    $submittedby = $_POST['submittedby'];


foreach ($_POST["xid"] as $index => $id) {
    
    $checkname = $_POST['checkname'][$index];
    $status = $_POST['btn'][$id];
    $comment = $_POST['xcomment'][$index];

echo $checkname;
echo "<br>";

echo $status;
echo "<br>";

echo $comment;
echo "<hr>";

// your database query here


}
```

See [Demo](https://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/SO_answer_16Mar2024.php)

Please choose the radio buttons, and enter the comments, then click the submit button and see the effect (Note : I have changed the above PHP part to simply display the submitted data, which you should revise to actually suit your database insert operation)

Comment: This only submits that status correctly. See my OP edit.

Comment: First follow-up:- Did you see any errors now ? (`Undefined array key "appnamesubmit", Undefined array key "date", Array to string conversion`, as in your question)

Comment: Uninitialized string offset 9 on line 12. This repeats from 9 to 31

Comment: ``` $checkname = $_POST['checkname'][$index];``` This is line 12

Comment: This works partially. Still not sending appname, submittedby, or datesubmitted. New code with edit in OP

Comment: Those appname, submittedby and datesubmitted should be stored (inputted by you) in the submission form . Did you actually do this part ??? (change all to to <input value="xxxx" .... > )

Comment: Im so stupid. I was more worried about the actual check submit itself. I didnt put that in, LOL. Your code works. Thank you